# How to use array of textbox in button_click method?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, textbox

I've create an array of textboxes of rows and colums in EnterColsAndRows class. I need to use it in button_click method to create an array of int variables for each row and column.

```
public partial class EnterColsAndRows : Form
    {
        public  int width_of_nonogram;
        public  int height_of_nonogram;
        public EnterColsAndRows(int width, int height)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            width_of_nonogram = width;
            height_of_nonogram = height;
            TextBox[] textBox1 = new TextBox[width_of_nonogram];
           TextBox[] textBox2 = new TextBox[height_of_nonogram];
            for (int i = 0; i < width_of_nonogram; i++)
            {
                textBox1[i] = new TextBox();
                textBox1[i].Text = "Col " + (i + 1);
                Point p = new Point(20, 30 * i);
                textBox1[i].Location = p;
                this.Controls.Add(textBox1[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < height_of_nonogram; i++)
            {
                textBox2[i] = new TextBox();
                textBox2[i].Text = "Row " + (i + 1);
                Point p = new Point(200, 30 * i);
                textBox2[i].Location = p;
                this.Controls.Add(textBox2[i]);

            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: You should declare `TextBox[] textBox1 = new TextBox[width_of_nonogram];` and `TextBox[] textBox2 = new TextBox[height_of_nonogram];`  in at the Form level instead of at the method level.

Comment: You should read [ask] and then make your question a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read about classes fields and properties

```
private TextBox[] textBox1;
private TextBox[] textBox2;;

...
public EnterColsAndRows(int width, int height)
{

    ...

    textBox1 = new TextBox[width_of_nonogram];
    textBox2 = new TextBox[height_of_nonogram];

    ...

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox1 != null && textBox1.Length > 0)
    {
        textBox1[0].Text = "Awesome, i am"
    }
}
```

**Further reading**

[Classes (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

[Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

Answer (score 0):

To access textbox array what you can do is :

```
foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
  if (x is TextBox)
  {
    var textbox = ((TextBox)x);//Your code goes here.
  }
}
```

With this you will be able to access all the textboxes, what you can do is assign name to the textboxes in the EnterColsAndRows function and use it in the above code.